# Compass 0.11.5 + Rails 3.1 + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to get Compass working on my dev machine and on an Heroku stack.
The steps I followed are :

- I installed the Compass gem via the Gemfile
- I ran the command that initializes the compass project inside my 3.1 rails app

  compass init rails . --using blueprint

I got these lines:

```
directory ./app/stylesheets/
directory ./app/stylesheets/partials/
create ./app/stylesheets/screen.scss 
create ./app/stylesheets/partials/_base.scss 
create ./app/stylesheets/print.scss 
create ./app/stylesheets/ie.scss
```

This is a bit suspicious: these files should be generated in the app/assets/stylesheets folder, right?

I added these 3 lines to my application.html.erb file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'screen.css', :media => 'screen, projection' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'print.css', :media => 'print' %>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie.css', :media => 'screen, projection' %><![endif]-->
```

When I launched compass watch, this is what I got from the terminal:

```
>>> Change detected to: ie.scss
   create public/stylesheets/ie.css 
   create public/stylesheets/print.css 
   create public/stylesheets/screen.css 
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

I followed the steps described on the compass website and the tutorial displayed after I initialized the project.

When I go on my app, the screen.css and the print.css are not loaded because their URL is /assets/screen.css.

Anybody had this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of compass posted a fix for rails 3.1 integration with compass - https://gist.github.com/1184843

There is also a different way to make it work - http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/07/12/sass-sprockets-compass-with-rails-3-1/